# Is it possible to see what of my content received awards?

Tags: steam

My Steam profile has a couple of awards, but I'm not sure where they came from. I remember receiving an email about this, but it's gone now.

Is it possible to find which of my content (comments, reviews, screenshots) received an award from Steam UI?

There is Profile > Activity > My Comment History to browse all my comments, but it doesn't show awards there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Steam, go to *Points Shop*:

[image]

In the left-hand menu, click on '*My Points History*':

[image]

Alternatively, when logged in to Steam on your browser, you can go to https://store.steampowered.com/pointssummary/.

Either way, you are given an overview of your Steam points balance, among which is '*Points from User Generated Content Awards*'.
By clicking '*Show Details*', you get an overview of the specific Awards and points you have received from other users, and on what content they were given:

[image]

**Click on '*Your User Generated Content*' to see the exact item that received the award.**

(You might have to click on 'Previous 90 Days' a few times.)

Comment: This is almost perfect, except there is a 2 week delay between getting an award and points for it. Nevertheless, accepting this answer, thank you!